# Are the temperature and fan speed normal in my laptop?

Tags: fan, temperature, speedfan, core, cpu-temperature

My laptop is **HP Pavilion DV6-6b51ea**. The laptop is around 5 years 10 months old.

**Configuration**:

- Intel Core i5 2430M 2.40 GHz
- 6 GB RAM
- x64 based processor
- ATI Radeon HD 6490M gpu
- Intel HD 3000 integrated GPU
- Hitachi 750GB Hard disk
- Windows 10 64-bit

I am using a software **SpeedFan 4.52** to see the fan speed and temperatures of CPU, HDD etc.

[[image: Please see the screenshot before reading the rest.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaLSF.png)

In the software, what does `core0`, `core1`, `temp1` mean? Are the temperatures normal? 
Is the fan speed `1785rpm` normal?

Is the software even giving the correct information?

[Task Manager screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrtA3.png)

Comment: Unless your system is randomly shutting itself off you can assume the temperature is fine.

Comment: it is not shutting itself off. But the fan noise is louder than average

Comment: what does `core0`, `core1`, `temp1` mean?

Comment: Oh. What is `temp1` ?

Answer (score 1):

`core0` and `core1` are the temperature sensors built in to the CPU cores themselves.

`temp1` would be a temperature sensor somewhere else on the motherboard. It could be somewhere near the CPU or built in to one of the other microchips on the motherboard.

Those temperatures look perfectly safe and normal. They are slightly higher than I would expect from a completely "idle" system but it could be that some system update or software is running and warming your CPU slightly.

The fan speed of `1785rpm` again seems slightly high, but what I would expect for a laptop CPU at that temperature.

Check task manager for programs that could be using the CPU.

If the temperature stays high and the fan speed persists over the course of a week then you may need to open the laptop up to clean dust out of the fan. Check your manufacturer for a guide on how to safely dismantle your laptop to clean the dust out.

Comment: I don't want to open my laptop as I am very far from expert. I know there are tutorial videos for dismantling a laptop but I don't want to risk it. The only option is to go to a laptop repair shop, but that would cost me at least 30 euro just for opening the laptop and cleaning the fan, and I don't want to spend that. **Two months ago**, I took my laptop to a repair shop and they cleaned everything inside the laptop and also changed the thermal pastes. How is it possible that the fan has gotten dirty again in such a short amount of time?

Comment: If they did what you said then it shouldn't have gotten that bad that quickly. How long has this been going on?  My guess would be that at the moment your machine is preparing itself to install the Fall Creators Update for Windows, or there is some other program using the CPU. Check the Task Manager as your next step.

Comment: Only 13% of the CPU is being used. See the screenshot. Then why is the temperature slightly higher?